# Is it possible to create a supression list purely based on domains (not full emails)? For example for competitors?

Tags: marketing-cloud, suppressionlist, exclusion-script

Is it possible to create a suppression list purely based on domains e.g. for competitor domains without having the full email address of these contacts. This would allow to automatically exclude any competitors from email sends.

I used to work with Eloqua and there it was possible and I found it very practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an exclusion script. Create a data extension with all the domains of your competitors and include a lookup in the exclusion script that will check for each subscriber that you send to if their domain exists in the data extension. If your AMPscript evaluates to TRUE, the send will be suppressed for that particular subscriber.

Exclusion script has to be just one line of code and will suppress the send only when it evaluates to TRUE, so you would have to use something like this:

```
Lookup("ExclusionDE", "Domain", "Domain", Substring(AttributeValue("emailaddr"),Add(IndexOf(AttributeValue("emailaddr"),"@"),1),100)) > 0
```

Read more on Adam's blog: https://sprignaturemoves.com/exclude-an-email-domain-from-a-send/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! We will try this...

Comment: Sure @ChristinaGstoettl - if you find this helpful, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to your SFMC rep about Domain Exclusion DEs. From [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5):

> Domain Exclusions - Select a data extension that contains a list of
>   email domains to exclude from the send. By selecting your domain
>   exclusion list, the system excludes any email addresses that use that
>   domain.

Also referenced in this [article by Guilda](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimizing-salesforce-marketing-cloud-9-features-you-wish-hilaire/):

> Domain Exclusion: From time to time have you seen domains that no
>   longer exist in your lists or data extensions or domains you want to
>   block all together from your sends? Are there certain domains you want
>   to block from your email sends? While your sending IP address
>   reputation may be good, you still want to exclude these domains.
>   Domain exclusion to the rescue. You need to create the Data Extension
>   with a DomainExclusion Template. Once this is created, the option will
>   show in the Audience section of your Send Definition. Populate your
>   data extension with the domains you want excluded (e.g.
>   mycompetitor.com). Voila!

As you can see there is very little official documentation on it (at least from a couple google searches) - which is why I would recommend talking to your rep.

This would require you adding the domain exclusion DE to each of your sends including triggers, UI, and send wizard emails.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an auto-suppression list that is populated by a SQL query to find all subscribers with one of your competitors domains. There is even a [field in the _Subscribers data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) to access this, but you could also use SQL like this:

```
SELECT EmailAddress 
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE RIGHT(EmailAddress, LEN(EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', EmailAddress)) IN ('domain1','domain2')
```

You would have to do a DE extract and import to the suppression list to get this to work, but you could also just generate this audience and use them as a regular exclusion audience for your send interactions.

If you need to apply this on the fly for a Journey/Trigger (but don't want to use auto-suppress), a more general solution would be to include an exclusion script in your triggered sends where you isolate these addresses via ampscript and then exclude them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!